# what is a curve ? Is the concept of derivative limited to curves only?

Tags: calculus, self-learning, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to understand derivative and I want to know intuitive and rigorous definitions for a curve and if derivative is lmited only to curves or not..

Comment: *Derivative* is relative to a *function* : a curve can be described by a function, but the notion of [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is the correct one to be used.

Comment: The derivatives are defined in terms of functions, not curves, though they have many applications in the theory of curves and surfaces. You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces

Answer (score 1):

In elementary calculus context, there is no need to rigorously define what it mean by "curve". Intuitively you can think of a curve as an arbitrary line that can be drawn in one stroke; the simplest curve is a straight line.

The concept of derivative originates from the problem of finding the slope of a curve; you may imagine that, if you are not aware of any calculus, how you may solve that problem. By treating a curve as the graph of a "continuous" function, we can make mathematically rigorous what it means by the slope of a curve at a given point in terms of the derivative of the function: "the slope of a curve at a given point" is rephrased as "the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function at the point".

Curves can be studied independently, but this is another story.

Answer (score 0):

A curve is the graph of an application \begin{align*}\gamma :A\subset \mathbb R&\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n\\ t&\mapsto (\alpha_1(t),...,\alpha_n(t))\end{align*}

where \begin{align*}
\alpha_i:A&\longrightarrow \mathbb R\\
t&\mapsto \alpha_i(t).
\end{align*}

And yes, derivative are limited to curve. For a surface or any other space... you will talk about differential and not derivative. For a curve, the derivative and the differential coincident.